# A question about the geometric interpretation of the conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, self-learning, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variable. Suppose $E[X|Y]=0$, we have
$$E[XY]= E[\, E[ XY |Y  ]\, ] = E[\, Y E[ X |Y  ]\, ]= E[0] = 0$$
A geometric intuition also corroborates this fact if we think $E[X|Y]$ and $E[XY]$ as being the projection of $X$ onto $Y$ and the inner product, respectively. That is, the equation above tells me that if the projection of $Y$ on $Y$  is zero, then $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal.

So I want to show the reciprocal: if $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal, i.e., $E[XY]=0$, then the projection of $X$ on $Y$ is zero, i.e., $E[X|Y]=0$.

I've been trying to show this, but I couldn't.

1. Is there any counterexample?
2. If there is a counterexample, why does it go against geometric intuition?

*The second question intrigues me more.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counter-example: Let $Y\sim N(0,1)$  and $X=Y^{2}$. Then $E[XY]=0$ and  $E[X|Y]=Y^{2}$. [Converses of true statements are often false].

About your intuition failing I can say the following:

$E[Y|X]$ is not the projection of $Y$ onto the **vector space spanned by $X$**. It is the projection of $Y$ onto the space of $X-$measurable functions. This last space includes $X^{2}$, for example, even though $X^{2}$ is not the vector space spanned by $X$. @AndréGoulart

Comment: Moreover this counter example works for any symmetric variable $Y$ for which $|Y|^3$ has finite mean. For instance, $Y$ uniform on $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: Thank you so. And what about the second question? I don't have much experience in mathematics, but I would like to understand better why geometric intuition fails. I think a more specific question is in what situations is the reciprocal true? Hilbert spaces?

Comment: My example is in the Hilbert space $L^{2}$. @AndréGoulart

Comment: I'm really confused. If $E[YX]=0$, this means that $Y$ and $X$ are orthogonal. So why is $E[Y|X]$ (projection of $Y$ into $X$) not $0$? I must be making some very silly mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: Yes, you are making a fundamental mistake. $E[Y|X]$ is not the projection of $Y$ onto the vector space spanned by $X$. It is the projection of $Y$ onto the space of $X-$measurable functions. This last space includes $X^{2}$, for example, even though $X^{2}$ is not the vector space spanned by $X$. @AndréGoulart

Comment: oh, now i get it. Then the projection is on the space of all functions of $X$. So, can I state that if $E[Y g(X) ]=0$ for any measurable function $g$ then $E[Y|X]=0$?